Chromium "Sandbox cannot access executable" (Selenium) (chromium) (Python)
I've been developing a web scraper with python and when initially creating the webdriver.Chrome object with Selenium.py, I consistently get a "Sandbox cannot access executable" error which doesn't stop the driver from running. I also get a "Network service crashed, restarting service." error right after the first error.
I am wondering what these errors mean and if this somehow affects efficiency or creates any type of problem I might fix? If these are irrelevant and there is a way to hide warnings like these I would also like to know.
I am on windows and am running chromium version 130.0.6723.91.
The exact errors are:
[7140:7192:1031/032730.812:ERROR:sandbox_win.cc(852)] Sandbox cannot access executable. Check filesystem permissions are valid. See <url shortener>.: Access  is denied. (0x5)
(url shortner is a link to https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/docs/design/sandbox.md#lpac-file-system-permissions)
and:
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:54369/devtools/browser/196df3d8-fd31-4291-a2ad-429e5246e824 [7140:17948:1031/032730.922:ERROR:network_service_instance_impl.cc(613)] Network service crashed, restarting service.
I've tried looking online but I haven't been able to figure out exactly what these errors mean. I read something about restricting certain processes to set permissions but I am wondering how this actually impacts runtime.

I would rather use playwright instead of selenium.

what OS/version and what user account does the script run as?

I am on windows and am running chromium 130.0.6723.91 . Forgot to mention chromium version so I edited the main post
